# How can I do a frequency count for words and phrases in the same TermDocumentMatrix using package tm, SnowballC, RColorBrewer, wordcloud and NLP?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-processing

I am trying to add in codes so that when I count keyword occurrences, I can see both single words and phrases in the variable "d". The count should also not be duplicated (if it comes up in single words, it should not appear in the phrases again). I am using the package "tm", "NLP", "RColorBrewer", "wordcloud" and "SnowballC".

```
text <- readLines(file.choose())
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))

toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\|")

docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("pictwittercom", "twittertrendingtopics", "wwwtrendinaliacom", "singaporetodayhtml", "aldubpanibagonglihim", "http", "https", "bitly", "pictwittercom", "dlvr", "sgt", "trndnl", "niall", "wwwswarmappcom", "kak", "mtbnn", "vmas", "lang", "youtubecom", "untuk", "dan", "bagus", "sakit", "membantu", "kahit", "lahat", "mga", "pag", "tao", "kung", "akan", "penyakit"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)

set.seed(1234)
    wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
              max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
              colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

The issue now is that when I print d into the console, only single words appear. I want to see both phrases and single words and the count should not be duplicated. Please advice as I have been looking through Stack Overflow for hours and still can't find a good solution.

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated and wondering if this is possible with existing packages that have been mentioned?

Comment: Appreciate any help which can be provided here. I have been looking through various threads and the solutions are not apparent. Is there a gap in terms of the coverage for the packages I am using? Would gsub() in a for loop be a reasonable remedy to this problem? Appreciate any help!